# Make a cross validation on a dataframe for an OLS regression model

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation

i have a dataframe like this (it's bigger and there are more features):

```
        Date  Influenza[it]  Febbre[it]  Cefalea[it]  Paracetamolo[it]  \
0    2008-01            989        2395         1291              2933   
1    2008-02            962        2553         1360              2547   
2    2008-03           1029        2309         1401              2735   
3    2008-04           1031        2399         1137              2296   
       ...              ...

     tot_incidence  
0           4.56  
1           5.98  
2           6.54  
3           6.95  
            ....
```

First of all i made a ols regression on the dataframe without splitting in training/test sets and this is the 'input configuration' that worked (`tot_incidence` is to predict, `Influenza[it]`, `Febbre[it]` and `Cefalea[it]` are the features):

```
fin1=fin1.rename(columns = {'tot_incidence':'A','Influenza[it]':'B', 'Febbre[it]':'C','Cefalea[it]':'D'})
result = sm.ols(formula="A ~ B + C + D", data=fin1).fit()
```

OK. Now i want to make a training and test set.

Tried classic split and k-fold

> 1° Classic split

Probably that's easier, I could do this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)
```

And then insert the variables in the OLS model:

```
x_train = sm.add_constant(X_train)
model = sm.OLS(y_train, x_train)
results = model.fit()
predictions = results.predict(X_test)
```

In this case how can i make the `x,y` from the dataframe to insert them in the `cross_validation.train_test_split` function?

> 2° K-fold (if too hard don't waste time on it)

For example i could do this:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,1:3]
Y = array[:,5]
num_folds = 10
num_instances = len(X)
seed = 7
kfold = cross_validation.KFold(n=num_instances, n_folds=num_folds, random_state=seed)
```

At this point i'm stuck, how can i insert this variable in the ols to make then the prediction? Is there a better way to make the training/test sets?

Answer (score 0):

> In this case how can i make the x,y from the dataframe to insert them in the cross_validation.train_test_split function?

You need to convert dataframe columns into inputs (`x,y`) that an algorithm can understand, i.e. convert columns of a dataframe into either numbers or categories, depending on the type of algorithm you are trying to perform.

1) Select the variable in your dataframe that is your response/predictor, i.e. your Y variable. Say that's `Influenza`:
`y = df.Influenze.values # convert to a numpy array`

2) Select the X variables, say `Febbre, Cefalea, Paracetamolo`:
`X = np.column_stack([df.Febbre.values, df.Cefalea.values, df.Paracetamolo.values])`

Now you can call the `cross_validation.train_test_split` function.

Note that if your variables are categories, then you'll have to use some sort of categorization, such as [one-hot](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).